# Syntax for adding values to the arraylist of array

Tags: java, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

How do you assign values to `ArrayList<int[]>`, like you do with 2D array `anArray[0][0] = val` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector<int[]> vector=new Vector<int[]>();
vector.get(0)[0]=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] row = list.get(rowNumber);
row[columnNumber] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a specified element at a specified position using the [add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `set` as described [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/vector_set.htm)

```
Vector<int[]> v = new Vector<int[]>[10];
v.set(0, new int[10]);
```

and then get a value

```
int[] curr = c.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

list.add(int index, String Element);

Answer (score 0):

you can add elements to arraylist using  **add**   metheod.

```
    int[] x={1,2,3,4,5};
 ArrayList<int[]> demo = new  ArrayList<int[]>();
    demo.add(x);
```

you can,  inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

```
  add(int index, E element)
```

**index** : index at which the specified element is to be inserted.
**element** element to be inserted here must be integer array

```
   demo.add(5, x);
```

element inserted in 5th position in arraylist